# Testflight app not updating

Tags: xcode, cordova, app-store-connect, testflight

I have this Cordova/Phonegap iOS app which I have submitted to Testflight for beta-testing.

However when I have pushed updates, the beta users have not had their apps updated, it's still the same app.

Find this really strange since I have verified in Xcode before I submit that it is the new code.

Things I have done:

1. Save code, commit and push to Github
2. Start Xcode, launch new project, checkout master-branch from Github.
3. Verify bundle ID, update build, and version numbering.
4. Archive, then submit to iTunes Connect
5. Distribute new version via iTunes Connect and disable old version.

Am pulling my hair right now. Have pushed 3 updates which haven't gone through. Any ideas?

Comment: Did the beta tester install the new version? It does not magically update the old app.

Comment: Yes, they installed it.

Comment: Is that fixed ?? what you did in such case ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar issue and this resolved it for me:

In iTunes Connect go to the prerelease page for your app, then toggle the TestFlight Beta Testing switch off and then back on again.

Edit - It may be irrelevant but I have to add a key in my Info.plist `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption`.

Setting this to "NO" solved my problem. It seems they have removed the option of setting "Missing Compliance" from App Store and added this key.

Please go through this link once for details,
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/itsappusesnonexemptencryption

Comment: Where is the prerelease page?

Comment: Can also check if TestFlight is encountering any outages:
https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you've filled out all the fields in the Build Information and hit save. I've had this same issue.

Comment: @SatoBolin he means in iTunes Connect under Test Information. You have to enter all the contact info and anything else they ask for. After that it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the build version (like 1.0.0 to  1.0.1) or just remove the previous build

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I was using Xamarin but essentially creating the archive and submitting it via XCode.

My archive was always the same version number, but each time I would increment the build number. They would be accepted in iTunesConnect and the previous builds would become `inactive` but I would be stuck at the point of having to invite testers to the new build. Clicking `invite testers` would only show me that I already had my internal testers selected, however the only build they could test would be the first one.

Solution I found was once the new build was active I would then have to switch off testing and switch it back on. This prompted the email to be sent inviting testers to the new update "build ##".

Comment: Just realised this is a duplicate answer... I up voted the original.. oops.

Answer (score 1):

I have to add a key in my Info.plist `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption`.

Setting this to "NO" solved my problem. It seems they have removed the option of setting "Missing Compliance" from App Store and added this key.

Please go through this link once for details, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/itsappusesnonexemptencryption

Comment: This worked for me. Even though the store was showing the dialog for setting the compliance option it did not seem to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to wait for Testflight to finish processing.