# Xamarin project some changes not applied when deployed to App Store

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019, testflight, xcode13

This has started since we updated Visual Studio and upgraded XCode to 13.
Our mobile app builds fine. We can see all out changes in the iPhone Simulator.
When we deploy to the App Store and view the app via TestFlight, only some changes appear.

For example:

1. We removed a tab from a TabbedPage. This removal we can see in the simulator, but not when deployed to TestFlight.
2. We updated the build number in the info.plist. We can see this change after app is deployed to TestFlight.

We have cleared bin and obj folders.

Any ideas people?

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.4

XCode 13.0 (13A233)

Comment: I have reviewed restarted all machines and cleaned the iOS solution. No go.

Comment: Did you add the key `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` and set it to `No` in info.plist ?  Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28245907/8187800.

Comment: Sadly, that is not the issue. This build/release worked before the VS/XCode13 update

Comment: Can you provide the version of the VS for windows/mac and Xcode ? We need to reproduce the problem .And also feel free to raise issue on github : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues and apple developer forum : https://developer.apple.com/forums/ .

Comment: Now added to original question @ColeX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only able to get working again after a full uninstall and re-install of Visual Studio.